# Extracting values from JSON with top level array using Jmeter JSON Extractor

Tags: json, path, jmeter, extractor

In my JMeter test plan, I have a sampler which returns the list of authors and their books in JSON format. I would like get the id of all authors only. That is, In this case, I should get [1,2,3] in a variable name, so that I can use a ForEach controller to initiate another sampler to get detail information about each author. I know I can use JSON extractor to get this, but I am not getting each data that I am looking for.

```js
    [
     {
      "firstName": "William",
      "lastName":"Shakespeare",
      "Title": "Mr",
      "id": "1",
      "books": [
       {
        "id": "WS1",
        "title": "King John",
        "year":"1596"
       },
       {
        "id": "WS2",
        "title": "Julius Caesar",
        "year": "1599"
       },
       {
        "id": "WS3",
        "title": "Romeo and Juliet",
        "year": "1595"
       }
      ],
      "Nationality": "English"
     },
     {
      "firstName": "Sidney",
      "lastName":"Sheldon",
      "Title": "Mr",
      "id": "2",
      "books": [
       {
        "id": "SS1",
        "title": "The Naked Face",
        "year":"1969"
       },
       {
        "id": "SS2",
        "title": "A Stranger in the Mirror",
        "year": "1976"
       },
       {
        "id": "SS3",
        "title": "Bloodline",
        "year": "1977"
       }
      ],
      "Nationality": "American"
     },
     {
      
      "firstName": "Eiichiro",
      "lastName":"Oda",
      "Title": "Mr",
      "id": "3",
      "books": [
       {
        "id": "EO1",
        "title": "Wanted",
        "year":"1992"
       },
       {
        "id": "EO2",
        "title": "Ikki Yako",
        "year": "1993"
       },
       {
        "id": "EO3",
        "title": "Monsters",
        "year": "1994"
       }
    
      ],
      "Nationality": "Japanese"
     }
    ]
```

Using JSON Extractor Post processor, when I used JSON Path expression $..id, it gives me all the ids, including ids of books too. For example, it returns
[1,WS1,WS2,WS3,2,SS1,SS2,SS3,3,EO1,EO2,EO3]. I think .. in JSON mean recursive lookup, which is not I want. I want the ids only from top level.
Can this be achieved using built-in JSON Extractor, or I have to use some sort of Groovy script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `..` operator stands for [deep scan](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators), if you want only top-level IDs you should use the following JsonPath expression:

```
$.[*].id
```

Demo:

[image]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor/)

Comment: thank you. this is what I am looking for. Thank you very much